# Android mock Picasso network response?

Tags: android, picasso, android-espresso

I am using espresso to test how the app behaves when Picasso returns specific responses such as 40x, 50x, images of extreme dimensions etc. For example,

```
if (path.endsWith("/image")) {
   return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(404);
}
```

I thought MockWebServer would intercept the calls but it's not. It is still making real network call. I think it is so because Picasso might be running its own Networking client.

Is there a way to tell Picasso to set base Url as localhost? How do you guys test this kind of scenario? Thank you.

Update 1: Init Picasso

```
public Picasso getPicasso() {
    if(picasso == null) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(requestInterceptor) 
                .addNetworkInterceptor(responseInterceptor)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        picasso = new Picasso.Builder(app)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                .build();
    }
    return picasso;
}
```

Comment: What's your Picasso setup? Are you just using `Picasso.with(context)`? Or are you doing something more fancy?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I have updated the post with how the picasso instance is initialized.

Comment: So since you're using the downloader from Jake, then `MockWebServer` should work perfectly. You can look [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader/blob/master/src/test/java/com/jakewharton/picasso/OkHttp3DownloaderTest.java) that Jake is using `MockWebServer` for his tests of the downloader.